# Getting value from input box in html in external Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page and and external JavaScript file. 
How do I access the value of an `input` tag from the HTML page in JavaScript? My HTML is as follows:

```
<form name="formxml">
<input type="text" name="xmlname"/>
<input type="submit" value="Click me please" onclick="loadxml()"/>
</form>
```

In the Javascript file, I was trying:

```
var name = document.formxml.xmlname.value
```

but this gives an error of "document.formxml is undefined"

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the external js can't find the form yet because it's parsed before the page is rendered? Not sure about it, but putting it in a function and calling the function on the page (when it's done loading) does work:

```
function foo () {
  var name = document.formxml.xmlname.value;
  alert(name);
}
```

and

```
<form action="" method="post" name="formxml">
  <input type="text" name="xmlname" value="123" id="xmlname">
  <input type="button" onclick="foo();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following after you add an id attribute to input tag

```
document.getElementById('id').value
```

Comment: An additional ID is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

maybe document.**forms**.formxml.xmlname.value

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
var name = document.forms[0].xmlname.value; //where [0] means the first form on the page
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = document.formxml.value; //Will not work in all browsers
var name = document.forms[0].xmlname.value; //safest if the form is the first on the page
var name = document.getElementById('inputId').value; //works in basically everything assuming the browser has DHTML (which is like everything).
```

The last one requires your input elem to have an id="inputId" added to it.

Also your code will work, assuming the form exists when the external js is loaded (which is why forms[0] will work here and formxml will not.

Comment: i tried all three of these. none of them are working. Are these codes supposed to work for the external javascript too??

Comment: by external javascript are you refering to importing it from a file like <javascript src="someplace" type="text/javascript">? Whether you do it that way or just embedd the code in your html it is the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
    function yourfunction()
    {
       var x = document.getElementsByName("fieldname").value;
    }
</script>
```