# How to get HTML form data in external JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to get access to the user inputted data in an external javaScript so I can use it to run the main script. My form is

```
<form action="scripts/Main.js" method="post">
     <label>
          Enter Pin:
     </label>
     <input type="text" id="pin" name="pin" /> <br>
     <label>
          Enter Username: 
     </label>
     <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
     <button type="submit">
          Submit Info
     </button>
</form>
```

I have no idea where to start in order to get and use the pin and name in the JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Getting HTML form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547035/javascript-getting-html-form-values)

Comment: you can find similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033345/getting-value-from-input-box-in-html-in-external-javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "an external JavaScript"?  What exactly is `action="scripts/Main.js"` attempting to do?  It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Possible dublicate of [addEventListener on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338476/addeventlistener-on-form-submit)